# Socket Communication Data Corruption on Write/Read

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I've got a C++ server that communicates with multiple clients. It uses a vector to store the handles to the sockets for those clients (playerSockets in the code below). At the end of the "game" I want the server to loop through that vector and write the same string to each client. However, sometimes the data that the client reads (and then displays) is "corrupted" as you can see in the screenshot, but this doesn't happen for the first client, only the second. I can't figure out why this is happening! I use this same technique (looping and writing) earlier in the program and it always works fine in that instance.

Here is what it is supposed to be shown:

[image: correct]

Here and here's what I get:

[image: incorrect]

Here is the server code that writes:

```
std::string announcement = "";
if (playerWon) {
    ...
    }
} else {
    announcement = "?No one won the game!\nGAME BOARD: " + cn.getGameBoard();
    for (int player : gameData->playerSockets) {
        write(player, announcement.c_str(), announcement.size() + 1);
    }
}
```

And here's the client code that reads. Keep in mind that more than one client is running and connected to the server, and this issue only happens with a client OTHER THAN the first client in the server's loop:

```
    static bool readMyTurn(int clientSd) {
        ...
        char buf[BUFSIZE];
        read(clientSd, buf, BUFSIZE);

        string myTurn(buf);
        cout << "MYMYMYMY: " << myTurn << endl;
        myTurn.erase(0, 1);
        cout << myTurn << endl;
        ...
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is my current code to read until encountering the null-terminator character.

```
string readOneStringFromServer(int clientSd, string &leftovers) {
ssize_t nullTerminatorPosition = 0;
std::string stringToReturn = "";

do {
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t bytesRead = read(clientSd, buf, BUFSIZE);
    nullTerminatorPosition = findPositionOfNullTerminator(buf, bytesRead);

    // found a null terminator
    if (nullTerminatorPosition != -1) {
        // create a buffer to hold all of the chars from buf1 up to and including the null terminator
        char upToNullTerminator[nullTerminatorPosition + 1];

        // get those chars from buf1 and put them into buf2 (including the null terminator)
        for (int i = 0; i < nullTerminatorPosition + 1; ++i) {
            upToNullTerminator[i] = buf[i];
        }

        // use buf2 to create a string
        stringToReturn += upToNullTerminator;

        // check if there are leftover bytes after the null terminator
        int leftoverBytes = bytesRead - nullTerminatorPosition - 1;
        if (leftoverBytes != 0) {
            // if there are, create a char array of that size
            char leftoverChars[leftoverBytes];

            // loop through buf1 and add the leftover chars to buf3
            for (int i = nullTerminatorPosition + 1; i < bytesRead; ++i) {
                leftoverChars[i - (nullTerminatorPosition + 1)] = buf[i];
            }

            // make a string out of those leftover chars
            leftovers = leftoverChars;
        } else {
            // if there are no leftover bytes, then we want to "erase" what is currently held in leftovers so that
            // it doesn't get passed to the next function call
            leftovers = "";
        }
    // didn't find one
    } else {
        stringToReturn += buf;
    }

} while (nullTerminatorPosition == -1);

return stringToReturn;
}
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to diagnose this remotely without a [mcve], but right away I can tell you you should be checking the result of the `read` call....

Comment: It looks like you're expecting one `write` call on the server end, to correlate to one `read` call on the client end. That's not a reasonable assumption. TCP/IP is a _stream_ protocol... Are you using a book on network programming for reference?

Comment: `write()` and `read()` send/receive arbitrary number of bytes in TCP. There is no guarantee that 1 `write()` will send the entire string, or that 1 `read()` will receive the entire string. Pay attention to their return values! They need to be called in loops to ensure all data is actually sent/received

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica That's correct - I'm expecting one write to one read. So... I thought that the write sent the contents of the buffer and the read would fill a buffer either until the buffer was full or there was nothing left to read. By "check the result of the read call" I assume you mean to check the number of bytes read?

Comment: Yes, read until you've the read the null terminator in this particular case. If there's more in the stream, it belongs to the next "message".

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok, makes sense. But how can you detect a single character from the stream? Do you have to read one character at a time and check it before the next read?

Comment: You can read `BUFSIZE` chars, look for a null terminator, if it's not there, add what you read to a buffer that can grow dynamically, like a `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` then read again. If you do find the terminator, add only the part up until the terminator to the buffer. The remaining parts of what you read, you save for the next time.

Comment: @TylerM. Nope, these are not blocking. And yes you must check the return value of API calls. You haven't verified that you're receiving any data at all! The stuff you're outputting to screen could just be unspecified values from an uninitialised array.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Ok, gotcha. That makes sense. I thought that read was blocking. So when I DO read on the client side into a buffer... what am I reading when I convert that data to a string and print the gibberish? I really did think that read blocked until there was something to read.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is there something like that that I'd have to do for the write call, as well?

Comment: @TylerM. Yes, but that's simpler since you don't have to save anything between iterations. Just write until you've written all bytes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Apologies, tab-completion fail.

Comment: @TylerM. That depends on what read returns, which you're not checking and therefore do not know

Comment: I've updated with a function I wrote to read using @TedLyngmo 's proposed solution.

Comment: Soon off to bed, but you need to check the return value from `read`. You may get `-1` or `0`. What would happen then?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, good point! I implemented that as well. Thank you so much for the help!